# Slow Query performance due to not exists in oracle

Tags: oracle, query-optimization, not-exists

this is my query it take more time to execute it can anyone make it faster!!!
I think the not exists causes more time consuming but I don't know how to convert it to left outer join with more conditions I have changed it many times but the result was changed with it.

thanks in advance.

Comment: This is a long query and you have provided no details about the data or data structure, nor the business logic you're implementing. Also it looks like you have an embedded function call `PCK_TAX_PERIOD.TXPRD_DATE_FN()`: what does that do? You cannot expect us to rewrite a query knowing nothing about what it's supposed to be doing. Please read [this post on Oracle tuning](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34975420/146325) then **edit your question** to provide more of the information we need.

Comment: @APC I have updated the query I need just to convert the not exist to join to increase the query execution speed!!!

Comment: You say in your question that you couldn't make the changes without affecting the result set. It's your data model and your business rules. So I think it's unlikely we can do it in complete ignorance. If you post some sample input data with the required output there is a chance someone might undertake the required surgery for you.

Comment: your join condition `( tabi.tax_account_No=ta.tax_account_no and tt.tax_Type_No!=2) OR( tt.tax_Type_No=2)` looks strange - do you really want all tt.tax_type_no = 2 rows to be joined to every row, regardless of the tax_account_no?

Comment: Also, you're not using anything from the establishment table; no columns, no predicates etc; you can remove that from the list of tables and joins.

Comment: _"I think the not exists causes"_  There is no need to guess.  Read up on `alter session set statistics_level=all;` and `DBMS_XPLAN.DISPLAY_CURSOR`.  It will tell you EXACTLY which steps in your execution plan are requiring the most work.

Answer (score 0):

As per basic tuning principle use exists or not exists if the query used inside not exists or exists has huge data.if it doesn't have huge data use IN or NOT IN instead

Also remove the distinct in SELECT DISTINCT t.tax_payer_no, taxestab.estab_no and use it in the CTE query and see how much time it makes

```
  with data as (
    SELECT t.tax_payer_no tax_payer_no,taxestab.estab_no estab_no.. rest of your query)
  select count(1),tax_payer_no,estab_no from data
     group by tax_payer_no,estab_no
```

Comment: No bro!
Not IN() also decrease the performance!!!
I want to change the NOT EXISTS() to left outer join!!!
is it possible???

Comment: can you post query timings for NOT EXISTS and NOT IN

Comment: in NOT IN it is timing is: fetched 50 rows in 191.627 seconds
and 
in NOT EXISTS: fetched 50 rows in 179.025 seconds

Comment: remove distinct in SELECT DISTINCT t.tax_payer_no, 
                                       taxestab.estab_no  and use it in the outer query and see how much time it makes